# Black screen after I login

Tags: xubuntu, multiple-monitors, login, screen

I switched to Xubuntu from windows and things have been pretty smooth until I tried to connect another monitor to my laptop (using vga). The screen suddenly went black, and since then, even with my external monitor disconnected, all I see is a black screen after I enter the login details. I can use the guest account to login without any problems.

I looked around before posting and found the exact same problem and the solution there was to delete this file `/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/displays.xml`, but unfortunately that file doesn't seem to exist in my pc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking for the file in 
`/home/USERNAME/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/displays.xml` (replacing USERNAME as appropriate) instead of 
`/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/displays.xml`.

The path to the file you wrote above is an absolute path starting in the root file system.

Comment: i have the path /.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml but i don't see the displays.xml file in it.

Comment: @fsociety You need to prepend that path with `~`.