# Black screen after login on account in Asus-laptop of 16.04

Tags: 16.04, graphics, screen, asus

This question had been asked multiple times but since they're almost older than two years, I will ask it again. The answers to those question couldn't help me either.

**My problem:**
After logging in on my account I get a black screen. I don't even see my cursor. I did not change major settings and the problem occurred randomly. When I start a guest session, everything works fine.
I don't know if it's worth mentioning but when I take a screenshot, I see two desktops in the output. Like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/411662/print-screen-captures-two-spaces-not-one). I don't have anything plugged in.

**Steps taken:**

- The solution in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449121/black-screen-after-login) question doesn't work. The file in the mentioned directory doesn't exist.
- Multiple answers on this subject mention (NVIDIA) drivers. As far as I know, no drivers have been installed/updated by me nor did I edit settings related to graphics. My laptop isn't Dual-Boot either and I erased the entire disk and replaced Windows with Ubuntu (through the Ubuntu installation screen). So existing drivers where probably deleted.

**My OS Type**: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (regular), 64-bit

**My Hardware**:

Hardware: Asus laptop R500V
Processor: Intel Core i5-3210M
CPU: 5GHz × 4
Graphics: Intel Ivy Bridge Mobile
Graphics Card: NVIDIA Corporation GF199m [GeForce 610M]

I hope I've given enough information and I hope you can help me.

Comment: If you don't even see a cursor it maybe HW-related. Give some info on your equipment. Sticker is on the bottom of the Laptop! What distro# are U on & what flavour?

Comment: @ellisistfroh: This might be an obvious thing but what does HW stand for? And what exactly do you mean by distro# and flavour? Like Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Unity? I'm just starting to learn this operating system

Comment: @Iarwain HW = Hardware.

Comment: @Iarwain He's asking which version of Ubuntu you are running (14.04, 16.04...) And also if it is regular Ubuntu, or Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu or Ubuntu Gnome.

Comment: @ellisistfroh Added my specs. Is this enough?

Comment: @Iarwain Yes, that's great.

Comment: Yes, thanks! That's fine. So it's clear that your Laptop has Nvidia-Optimus-Technology: Have been looking at [Wikipedia] for your CPU. So the IGP is a Intel HD4000

[Wikipedia]:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_i5_microprocessors

Comment: If it works in the guest profile it's clearly an issue of the configuration in your user profile. Could you please try to [reset the Unity configuration](/q/17610/175814) (assuming you're using Unity)? Make a backup if you care about possibly restoring (parts of) it.

Comment: @DavidFoerster yeah but.... Optimus is undoubtedly the cause of the issue here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out why the screen turns black when I login on my personal account. It appears I have accidentally pushed a button that toggles between monitors/beamers when connected. When nothing is connected to the laptop the build-in screen still turns off. This is done by pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>. This is applicable for the **Asus R500V series**

My thanks to the people who tried to help me. I'm in the process of learning Ubuntu and your suggestions/answers helped my understanding of the OS.

Comment: So I wonder why removing .Xauthority worked in the first place then...

Comment: @ larwain: Mark your answer as solving the problem, pls. Lucky to hear it was not a more serious issue :-)

You could check if you have kscreen installed: `dpkg-query -l kscreen`

Comment: @ larwain: Mark your answer as solving the problem, pls. Lucky to hear it was not a more serious issue :-) You could check if you have kscreen installed: dpkg-query -l kscreen

The counter-check would be to see if you could configure your laptop-monitor as main-screen via Kubuntus System-Settings.

Comment: @AndroidDev As far as I can tell, .Xauthority stores credentials in cookies for Xsessions. It is used to authenticate connections to the display. Maybe deleting the file resets the configuration to the build-in monitor. Haven't got a clue why it would be reversed after a second reboot. Do you think it's worth a seperate question? Source: http://askubuntu.com/a/300737/558082

Answer (score 3):

There are *many* possible causes for this problem. And thus, there are many solutions, some of which might work for someone else but not you.

That said, give this a try:

1. Open up `tty1` on the logon screen by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
2. Login at the prompt.
3. Then run these commands:

   ```
   sudo rm .Xauthority
   sudo shutdown -r now
   ```

Comment: This works, but only once. When I restart after the `sudo shutdown -r now` everything works. But when I reboot after that, `.Xauthority` is yet again present and my screen black. I have to delete it again to log in.

Comment: @Iarwain - Well at least it's a temporary fix. I'll do some research for you.

Comment: After a few restarts and reboots this solution stopped working. `.Xauthority` is still present but deletion is not a fix anymore after a few times

Comment: @ Android Dev: Maybe the access-rights in the home-folder are bowed? @ larwain: Did you ever start a GUI-program with preceeding `sudo`? It is to be preferred to use `pkexec` instead. Anyway there are logfiles to interpret, see `/var/log/xorg.0.log` for the one of the current session. Previous ones show higher numbers.

Comment: @ellisistfroh - I thought it was preferred to use gksudo?

Comment: @ Android Dev: That would need a separarte discussion, `gksu` would need to have to be installed. Developers decided that packagekit would do the job pretty well.
 ---  
@larwain. Added a thanks above, and corrected some typos in your question (for our eyes to charm). ;-) Will continue here now.