# Display issues with Asus R500V and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys, display, asus

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a Asus R500V series laptop, which had Windows as its previous OS. This laptop has an <kbd>Fn</kbd> button to access some hotkeys. <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>f8</kbd> toggles between screens if an external monitor or beamer is connected. This has four modes: laptop screen turned of, laptop shows only the wallpaper and the windows on the other source, external monitor and laptop are duplicates and laptop screen is a duplicate but smaller (black bars on either side).

My problem is this: Every time I boot my laptop and log in, the fourth mode is active (screen is a duplicate but smaller with black bars). I always shutdown with a normal screen. So whenever I log in, I have to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>f8</kbd> to have my normal screen. This problem has no impact on other functionality but is just really annoying.
[This isn't the first time I had issues with these buttons](https://askubuntu.com/questions/791892/black-screen-after-login-on-account). This has been resolved but I wonder why my current problem exists. I cannot recall any changes I made related to graphics.

**My OS Type**: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (regular), 64-bit

**My Hardware**:
Processor: Intel Core i5-3210M
CPU: 5GHz × 4
Graphics: Intel Ivy Bridge Mobile
Graphics Card: NVIDIA Corporation GF199m [GeForce 610M]

---

I'm not a native English speaker so I welcome any suggestions for a more readable text.

Comment: I can reproduce similar problem in Asus Zenbook UX303UA, both with `xserver-xorg-video-intel` and `modesetting` and with/without any customizations in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`. - - The artifacts are little different however. The artifact depends on which mode you ended your system. It can be as you describe in your earlier thread, or like here. However, I cannot get smaller view of the main display any way. Artifacts like hovering bars for short-term are possible. - - Can you take a video recording, make it a gif and add it here, please?

Comment: The artifact is also not NVidia related.